# Add reminder notification on apple watch with different different repeat interval

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, apple-watch

I am working on an apple watch app where I need reminder user notifications to awake user.

I am able to Set `UserNotification` with make `repeat: true` and it will remind the user every day.

But what I need is on single-day app will notify as per user selection like below.

if the user selects 3 min ideal time that every 3 min user got a notification with a vibration on the watch.

same with 5 min, 10 min, and 15 min.

*I am using the below code for `UserNotification`.*

```
func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
        let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Test Reminder"
        content.body = "Show More detail in Body!"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logo", ofType: "png") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            
            do {
                let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "logo", url: url, options: nil)
                content.attachments = [attachment]
            } catch {
                print("The attachment was not loaded.")
            }
        }
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

By using the below trigger with **`repeats: true`**

```
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)
```

it's repeating on next day same time.

Is there any way or method to set repeat after the specified interval as per user selection?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [`UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger) instead of a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`.

For example:

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 2*60, repeats: true)
```

That would create a trigger that fires every 2 minutes. `timeInterval` is the number of seconds between firing each notification.

Comment: great solution But I have one question when it will stop notifying or how long it will repeat on user iPhone or Watch ?

Comment: Let Me try it first Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Glad I could help, and remember to mark the answer as accepted if it works. For your question, the notification *should* repeat indefinitely until you remove it, but there have been some reports of it stopping after a few hours for some users on iOS 10.

Comment: @Coder256 I have a scenario where I am not receiving my local notifications on watch side in case if app is in background and screen is not turned on. Is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: @G.Abhisek No, that's strange. I don't really know what would cause that if notifications from other apps work on the watch and if notifications from your app do work on the phone. Maybe verify that Settings -> Notifications -> Your App and Watch -> My Watch -> Notifications -> Your App are set up right.

Comment: It happens in case of local UNUserNotifications, I have followed the above code. Do we need to have any additional notification settings?

Comment: I meant to check that the notifications for your app were set up properly on the device. If you are sure of that though, then maybe file a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com) with your code and the issue.